# Power BI Query To Find List Overlap

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am working on a report in PowerBI to determine which of our current volunteers has registered to volunteer next year.

The data is in a SQL server DB and has the following table structure:

Committees (Committee Info)
--Committee Membership (Current Volunteers)
--Committee Nominations (Those who have volunteered for next year)

Assuming the relationship between the tables keys are UserID and CommitteeID what would be the easiest way in PowerBi to get a table of Current Members of the committee with a true/false column indicating if they have been nominated this year?

Comment: You are giving us almost nothing to go on. Please post some minimal reproducible sample data and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INTERSECT() will do that. But without data, it's harder to tell. You could return a list of PersonID's from Committee Membership table and then a list of PersonID's from the Person table and then it's just

INTERSECT('Person'[PersonID],Membership[PersonID])

Comment: Thank you, new to DAX and wasn't aware of intersect. 

I can take it from here I think.